# nuget push azure devops artifacts failed

Tags: python, azure-devops, nuget

I am using the below command

```
nuget.exe push -Timeout 2147483 -Source "python-ml" -Apikey az -Verbosity Detailed ./python.spec.1.1.0.nupkg
```

the nupkg file size is 380MB. I am able to upload packages of size 1 MB but the above package is giving the below error

*

```
Error while copying content to a stream.
  Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
  An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Error while copying content to a stream. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndMultipleSend(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndMultipleWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Http.StreamToStreamCopy.BufferWrittenCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Protocol.ServerWarningLogHandler.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Protocol.StsAuthenticationHandler.<SendAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Protocol.HttpSourceAuthenticationHandler.<SendAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Protocol.HttpRetryHandler.<>c__DisplayClass2_1.<<SendAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Protocol.TimeoutUtility.<StartWithTimeout>d__0`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Protocol.HttpRetryHandler.<SendAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Protocol.HttpSource.<GetThrottledResponse>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Protocol.HttpSource.<ProcessResponseAsync>d__18`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.PackageUpdateResource.<PushPackageToServer>d__23.MoveNext()
```

*

Please provide some guidance. I am stuck not able to upload large files to Azure DevOps artifacts.

Comment: Did you try other networks? Did you get a 503 error?

Comment: Thanks @HughLin-MSFT I tried on another network and it worked and also it worked after increasing the RAM on my VM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried on another network and it worked and also it worked after increasing the RAM on my VM in the current network